# Redirecting back to JQTouch App

Tags: jqtouch

Running JQTouch app from iPhone Home Screen. Doing a Facebook login which redirects the user to Facebook then back to the JQTouch app but in a safari browser. In this case of the FB login, it appears any cookies that are set while in the safari browser, don't seem to be visible when the JQTouch app is launched from the home screen.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

login using open graph.. it has a redirect call..